# How to add legend to geom_ribbon plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have simple plot

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = sort(rnorm(100)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_ribbon(data=df[df$y < 0, ], aes(ymin=y,ymax=0), fill="blue", alpha=0.5) + 
    geom_ribbon(data=df[df$y > 0, ], aes(ymin=0,ymax=y), fill="orange", alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

I would love to add legend explaining blue and orange regions. Tried adding `show.legend = TRUE` inside `geom_ribbon` but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you change the `aes` to something like `aes(ymin=0,ymax=y, fill = "A")` and remove the other fill argument, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(data=df[df$y < 0, ], aes(ymin=y,ymax=0, fill="negative"), alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_ribbon(data=df[df$y > 0, ], aes(ymin=0,ymax=y, fill="positive"), alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive" = "orange", "negative" = "blue" ), 
                    breaks = c("positive", "negative")) # this controls the order of appearance
```

[image]